CVE-2021-46848 against libtasn
I'm using ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS focal. Looking for CVE-2021-46848 patch in this ubuntu release. From the below link, looks like it is in "Needs evaluation" stage.
https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2021-46848
Can you please let me know the plan for this release?
Thanks,
Peri.

Also please let me know whether the fix is needed in 20.04  LTS focal. if yes, will the same patch (16.04 LTS xenial - Fixed 4.7-3ubuntu0.16.04.3+esm3) applicable for this release as well ?

Hello. Most people here are not from Canonical, but someone with knowledge from the security team can possibly chime in. But generally, this site is not the place to discuss status for specific CVE's.

Also, please note the comment from the security team (Marc Deslauriers): "out of bounds read in API when using invalid value, not likely to be exploitable in any way"

Thanks for your help and response.
I understand that this CVE will not be likely exploitable and in 20.04 LTS focal this fix is applicable and needed. Can you please let me know the procedure to get this patch into 20.04 Ubuntu release ?

Please let us know the right forum to discuss on CVE queries.

Try Discourse, this is more the Ubuntu developer forum: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/

Thank you! will discuss in the Ubuntu developer forum.
