CVE-2021-46848 against libtasn in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS focal
I'm using ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS focal. Looking for CVE-2021-46848 patch in this ubuntu release. From the below link, looks like it is in "Needs evaluation" stage.
https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2021-46848
I understand that this CVE will not be likely exploitable and in 20.04 LTS focal this fix is applicable and needed. Can you please let me know the procedure to get this patch into 20.04 Ubuntu release ?
Thanks,
Peri.

Earlier had a discussion in the ubuntu support page.
Below is the link :
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1531357/cve-2021-46848-against-libtasn.
Snap shot from the old query:
Also, please note the comment from the security team (Marc Deslauriers): "out of bounds read in API when using invalid value, not likely to be exploitable in any way"
Based on the provided info, we assumed that issue is present in 20.04 version as well. so we requested for the patch details.
If it is in "Evaluation" stage, can you please let us know when the evaluation will be completed ?

We are your fellow users who volunteer our time to answer questions. We are not a reminder service or a customer service department. Use your own calendar to remind you to revisit the issue, just like the rest of us do.
